# MongoDB. How to use sorting, search and limit in aggregation correctly

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate, limit, skip

Suppose I have 10 million documents.
I need to skip the last 5 documents and get the last 10 documents.

This code works fast

```
documents.find({user: 'demo'}).sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(5).limit(10)
```

This code works very very slowly and loads the system heavily.

```
documents.aggregate([
  { $match: { user: 'demo' } },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
  { $skip: 5 },
  { $limit: 10 },
])
```

This will work quickly if the match is moved to the end, but then the results will be incorrect.
Help me figure out how to write a query correctly using aggregate

Comment: Are you sure?  The two code samples should behave the same

Comment: absolutely sure

Comment: Can you share the explain please?

Comment: You may want to refer the manual topic Aggregation Pipeline Optimization - with the sub-topics _$sort + $match Sequence Optimization_ and the _Improve Performance with Indexes and Document Filters_.

Comment: Do you have an index on `{name:1, _id:-1}`

Comment: There are indexes, but the question is not about that. Why does the first one work fast and the second one takes a long time?

I want to use aggregate, but I can't. I don't understand why

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I have version 4.0.6